# How to get the series of points that are generated with "click to add" in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

You can ask the user to supply data by clicking to adding points to a char, see [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-click-to-add).
But I don't know how to retrieve those points and send them back to the server (with a POST or AJAX, whatever). I just want to know how to get them in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the `chart` variable defined like this in javascript:

```
<!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            ...
        });         
    });
</script>
```

Access the new points like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printObject(o) {
        var out = '';
        for (var p in o) {
            out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
        }
        alert(out);
    }

    $("#clickme").click(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
            printObject(chart.series[0].data[i]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps even simpler than that, if you use the event/click function in the demo that you linked to, you can capture the values before the addSeries call:

```
...
click: function(e) {
    // find the clicked values and the series
    var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
        y = e.yAxis[0].value,
    series = this.series[0];

    //Do something fun here w/the points: x,y
    ....
    //Stop doing something fun here w/the points    
    // Add it
    series.addPoint([x, y]);
}
....
```